# Counting Down in jQuery with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a small plugin that will animate the countdown.

However, for some reason it's not working. Here is the code:

```js
$(window).onload(function() {
  $('.three').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.three').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.two').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.two').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.one').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.one').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.oneone').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.oneone').fadeOut('slot');
  $('.vote').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.vote').fadeOut('slow');
  $('html').effect('shake');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="oneone">0.5</div>
  <div class="vote">VOTE!</div>
</div>
```

I want this countdown to appear on window load and with css I would style.
But first I want to have a countdown: 
3
2
1
0.5
VOTE!

the main class will have the highest z-index.

Comment: The calls to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` don't block; the fading happens via timer callbacks. They're not synchronous.

Comment: I'd have kept a single element and animated it's text with counter down

Comment: I'm not that good in this, sorry.. :)

Comment: Try substituting `"slow"` for `"slot"` at `$('.oneone').fadeOut('slot');`

Comment: Did that, nothing happened.

Comment: Also substitute `document` for `window` . Is jQuery UI loaded into document for `.effect()` method to be defined ?

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question. Probably wasn't explained good enough.

Comment: So your problem is that all the functions are executed at the same time, isn't it?

Comment: I want them executed one by one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to do this concept with the use of `closure`,

```
var divs = $("div[class]");
var scope = null;

for(var i=0;i< divs.length;i++){
  scope = function(x){
    setTimeout(function(){
      x.show("slow").prev('div').hide("slow");
    },i * 2000);
  };

  scope(divs.eq(i));
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbw5Lsoc/1/)

Comment: Neat solution!. I didn't know closures could be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be sure that your script is located AFTER the inclusion of the jquery script. You can add them on the head section of your html:

```
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('window').ready(function() {
        ...
```

Then, if you want every effect to happen after the previous, you would need to chain them. However, you may want to hide all the elements initally like this:

```
<script>
  $('window').ready(function() {
    $('.three').hide();
    $('.two').hide();
    $('.one').hide();
    $('.oneone').hide();
    $('.vote').hide();

    $('.three').fadeIn('fast', '', function() {
      $('.three').fadeOut('slow', '', function() {
        /* chain the rest of the events...*/
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have you up, but you should know that 'window' should not be inside of the quotations.